# Dynamically dimension/populate a 2D array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an interesting problem. I need to fill in a 2D array with data, but I don't know how many data points there are until after the array is populated.

```
Dim finalArray(0 to 500000, 0 to 3)
R=0

For Each index in someDictionary
    If Not someDictionary.item(index)(1) = 0
        finalArray(R,0) = someDictionary.item(index)(1)
        finalArray(R,1) = someDictionary.item(index)(2)
        finalArray(R,2) = someDictionary.item(index)(3)
        R = R + 1
    End If
Next index
```

The issue is that I don't know how many items will be in the dictionary, nor how many will be nonzero. The only way I know is after I run the loop and have a count R.

Currently I'm printing the entire 500k row array to Excel, which is usually 100-400k rows of data with the rest blank. This is ungainly, and I would like to re-dimension the array to be the correct size. I can't use `ReDim` because I can't delete the data, and I can't use `ReDim Preserve` because it's 2-dimensional and I need to reduce the rows, not columns.

Comment: At the cost of taking two passes over the data, you could have a collection of collections (1 collection for each row) which you afterwards turn into a single 2-dimensional array. Collections are in many ways the most flexible data structure in VBA.

Comment: What about passing the info to a new array of the correct size and then dumping the old one?

Comment: Why not switch the position of rows and columns in your array then you will be able to redim the rows.

Comment: @ Forward Ed I'm afraid that would require looping through every item in the old array, which might be costly for this amount of data. Is there a way to assign the values directly?

Comment: @ INOPIAE That's an interesting idea. I may give that a shot. Is there an efficient way to transpose the array before I print it?

Comment: How you're doing it is fine.  But when you go to output the array, instead of outputting the entire array, just go up to R.  Something like: `Range("A1").Resize(R, 3).Value = finalArray`  so that it only spits out the populated data.

Comment: @ Tigeravatar this worked! Thanks!

Now what I would REALLY like to do is increase the size of the finalArray dynamically as data is added so I'm not eating up memory for a 500000 row array for the entire runtime of my sub. But maybe that's a battle for another day.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim finalArray()
    Dim R As Long

    For Each Index In someDictionary
        If Not someDictionary.Item(Index)(1) = 0 Then R = R + 1
    Next Index

    ReDim finalArray(0 To R, 0 To 3)

    R = 0

    For Each Index In someDictionary
        If Not someDictionary.Item(Index)(1) = 0 Then
            finalArray(R, 0) = someDictionary.Item(Index)(1)
            finalArray(R, 1) = someDictionary.Item(Index)(2)
            finalArray(R, 2) = someDictionary.Item(Index)(3)
            R = R + 1
        End If
    Next Index
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options

1. Redim the array as needed rather then create up front (which I think is better than looping through the array twice :)). I have added this given your comment to *tigeravatar*
2. Transpose the array to redim the first dimension
3. Ignore the redundant data as per *tigeravatar*

***Option 1***

*note I have flipped the data to make the point around testing for ReDim as you go rather than define an array size up front - it could well argue this changes the nature of the question but I thought the technique worth pointing out. Option2 shows how to transpose the array regardless*

```
Sub SloaneDog()
    Dim finalArray()
    Dim R As Long
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim lngCnt2 As Long

    lngCnt = 100
    ReDim finalArray(1 To 3, 1 To lngCnt)

    somedictionary = Range("A1:C3001")

    For lngCnt2 = 1 To UBound(somedictionary, 1)
           finalArray(1, lngCnt2) = "data " & lngCnt2
           If lngCnt2 Mod lngCnt = 0 Then ReDim Preserve finalArray(1 To 3, 1 To lngCnt2 + lngCnt)
    Next

End Sub
```

***Option 2***

```
Sub EddieBetts()
Dim X()
Dim Y()
Dim LngCnt As Long

ReDim X(1 To 1000, 1 To 3)
Debug.Print UBound(X, 1)

LngCnt = 100

Y = Application.Transpose(X)
ReDim Preserve Y(1 To UBound(Y, 1), 1 To LngCnt)
X = Application.Transpose(Y)
Debug.Print UBound(X, 1)

End Sub
```